# How to enable bottom navigation bar for only one class

Tags: ios, objective-c

Okay so this may seem a little strange, but here is my issue. I have a storyboard that is connected to my ViewController class (Let's call it mainViewClass). In this class the storyboard is displaying my tab bar. I also have a separate class which is a UITableViewController (let's call it TableViewClass) that is being displayed within the same ViewController that the storyboard is connected (mainViewClass).

So once I push to mainViewClass from my previous view it displays a translucent bottom bar as well as the tab bar from my storyboard. So I tried:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

and this ends up hiding both bottom bars in my mainViewClass. Is there a way to either disable the bottom bar in one class or perhaps create a conditional statement that would only display the tab bar?

Comment: FYI - the bottom bar is a toolbar. The top bar is a navigation bar.

Comment: try to show & hide bottombar in viewwillappear method of your controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your viewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
}
```